# Using Django User object in Android

Tags: android, django, session-cookies, django-users, django-sessions

I have an Android application, interacting with a Django API, which also hosts a website.

On the Django website, the user logs in with Google+/Facebook/Twitter (using [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)) and all subsequent requests contain a user object, which identifies the user. I assume this is done via cookies.

I want to implement the same functionality in my Android application. The application logs the user in with Google+/Facebook/Twitter, then sends the access token to the API, which logs the user in.

**What do I need to pass back to the Android application, and then back to the API with every request in order to have Django recognize the logged in user?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this. After logging the user in in `Django` you return **`request.session.session_key`**. You store this in the application and whenever you need to make an authenticated request you pass it back as a `POST` parameter.

In `Django`, you can create a decorator as such to automatically transform this into a [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) object in the request:

```
def extract_user(function):
    def handle_extraction(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Try to store the request.user if a session id is specified.
        if request.POST.get('SESSION-ID'):
            request.user = get_user_from_request_w_session_id(request)

        # Execute the function.
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return handle_extraction
```

Every function that expects an authenticated user is now annotated like this:

```
@extract_user
def my_function(request):
    ...
```

If you want to use [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) you can do that as well, just make sure to have the annotation **AFTER** `@extract_user`, as such:

```
@extract_user
@login_required
def my_function(request):
    ...
```

Comment: how should I post session-id? In header or normally?

Comment: @SMahdiS, you pass it back as a POST parameter.